# Delete from 2 tables using cascade and join table in sql and c#

Tags: sql, database-design

I have a Winforms application which uses a database.

Now in the database I have these tables:

1. `table A` (PK = Identity - auto increment)
2. `table B` (PK = Identity - auto increment)
3. `table C` (FK = table A's PK and table B's PK)

Tables A and B are strangers so I added the table C to connect them.

I'm trying to do a cascading delete, so when I'm deleting a row from table A, it will delete the related rows from tables B and C.

I set the relation between tables A and C and B and C.

But when I'm deleting one row from table A it deletes from table C but not from B.
why?

I can't set table C to be the parent of table B because the primary key...

Comment: It is impossible to using cascade deletion. Try use trigger.

Comment: If I could I would.. but this is one of the requirements

Comment: Suggest you to use store procedure, to delete all you need to delete in one transaction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to add specific treatment to delete your data when you wish cascade treatment. best practise, in order to control your deleting system.

Comment: yes you can use inner join in order to delete theses datas. or sub query whith IN Or EXISTS (I prefer EXISTS)

Comment: ok.. there is any best way from inner join? something with the relationships between the tables? I tried with no luck

Comment: actually no.. because I used visual studio to set the relationships between the tables.. using the DB diagram

Comment: yes, I know what the query should be.. but is it will work when also when I first delete from table A ?

Comment: firstly delete your A, secondly delete B , and in the last you delete link table your C

Comment: thanks.. I thought the cascade option will do this work.. I just spent on this a lot of time..